# bash sed with /^$/d;G command

Tags: linux, bash, sed

i have a problem about sed:
suppose stuff in file.txt is like:

```
one


two
three
```

then i run:

```
sed '/^$/d;G' file.txt
```

i think the process should be like:

```
for line in file {
    pattern_space = line
    if (pattern_space == "\n") then pattern_space = ""
    pattern_space = pattern_space + "\n" + hold_space
    print pattern_space
}
```

so, i think the result should be like:(with blank line untouched, non-blank line followed by a line)

```
one



two

three
```

but, the reality is:

```
one

two

three
```

as if i had run **sed '/^$/d' file.txt | sed G**, i am confused by this.
can you tell me what is the right process? is there something i misunderstood?
/br
ruan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `d` ends the processing of that line immediately, without (the default) printing at end-of-script.  If you want to skip the rest of the script but still do the end-of-script action, use `b` instead. The default `b`ranch target is end-of-script.

Comment: hi, @jthill, i want ask a little more, please. From manual it says, "n N    Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space", when i use **n**, why the origin stuff in pattern space is printed out? e.g, "sed 'n;d' file.txt", this command just cut off even lines. i think there should be nothing to output because **read next line into**. origin stuff in pattern_space should be disappear, but it is not

Comment: I don't know where you're getting that manual, [the real one](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) says ---  `n`
If auto-print is not disabled, print the pattern space, then, regardless, replace the pattern space with the next line of input. If there is no more input then sed exits without processing any more command